# Are there any hacks to style based on input value with just CSS?

Tags: html, css

For checkboxes it's possible to style based on dynamic value like:

```
input[type="checkbox"] { ... }
input[type="checkbox"]:checked { ... }
```

And I can use `:before` / `:after` as well to make dynamic value affect other things on the page.

So I tried doing the same to text inputs, but this selects based on initial value attribute, not on dynamic value:

```
input[type="text"][value="X"] { ... }
```

And there's also styling of options, but it only applies to its display when selection dropdown is open (and only in Chrome, not Firefox):

```
option:selected { ... }
```

So is there any way to style document based on text or select's dynamic value with pure CSS?

I know there are fairly simple javascript solutions.